# How to Update a Database while typing without leaving a page?

Tags: php, database

I know that there are many others question about this topic but unfortunatly (my knowledge are too low in AJAX and PHP) I didn't get how to make it work. So please excuse me if this question is redundant or already done, but I need some more "pratical" explanation to understand the issue better.

So here the topic:

---

- I have a game where all of the player have their character sheets
  hosted in a site.
- The Character's Sheets are made by several `<input>` tag and the
  players just fill them in. So, for example my Strenght score is
  inside an input and so on.
- I'm storing all of this data inside a Database
- from what I've learned so far I can only "save" the data by "Posting" it and refreshing the page.

**My Question** Is it possibile to "update" the database when blurring from an `input` to another (whith "onBlur") without exiting the page?

---

So for example here I have an example input:

```
<input name="spell_school" type="text" class="i50xauto" 
       placeholder="School" 
       value="<?php echo $row_rs_npc_erky_school['spell_school']; ?>">
```

I have to add some onBlur function?

Thanks for the help

Comment: yes, you can update the database "onBlur" event. And your assumption is correct, AJAX is needed here

Comment: you can do it using ajax

Comment: Step 1: Create the HTML form and PHP script which will process the data and then the AJAX will be easy.

Comment: is it possible for you to add some example? I'm little retarded on PHP and ajax..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need a player ID or similar on the page, perhaps in a hidden field?

You can then make the ajax call

```
$(".i50xauto").blur(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url:  'path/to/saveToDB.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
         player_id: $("#player_id").val(),
         spell_school: $(this).val()
      }
   });
});
```

Then inside the PHP file (lets call it saveToDB.php), you can update the database as you normally would, accessing the passed data via POST variables:

```
$_POST['spell_school']

$_POST['player_id']
```

Comment: ah ok, so nothing really complex, but let me ask you another question. That PHP file how I structure it?